# how to fix Comodo SSL certificate on Django app not trusted?

Tags: django, ssl-certificate

I have a **comodo positive SSL** certificate. put it on my server and started my server using this:

```
python manage.py runserver_plus --cert-file /my/cert --key-file /my/key 0.0.0.0:443
```

but it is not trusted in browsers yet. shows this:
[image]

I passed my files that have same name with my domain to **runserver_plus**. I think maybe i used wrong files.
now i want to know what is my problem?

Answer (score 0):

What you have is not a certificate signed by a Comodo certificate authority (CA). It seems to be self-signed given that the issuer and subject appear to be the same.

Two solutions:

- Accept this certificate in the web browser settings.
- Or don't used a self-signed certificate. I doubt however that you can find a CA that will issue you a certificate for localhost.